# Undefined attribute name (data-toggle)

Tags: eclipse, jsp, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter bootstrap in `JSP(Java Server Pages)` in eclipse. I am trying to use twitter log in/signup form in navbar(navigation-bar), but it gives a warning `Undefined attribute name (data-toggle)` Following code gives warning `data-toggle="dropdown"`.

Comment: And yes path to .js is not a conflict I guess.

Comment: Post part of the code or create jsfiddle

Comment: As well as which Eclipse version this is.

Comment: Could it possibly be a *doctype* issue? Even though `data-toggle` isn't valid HTML4 it still works in browsers, however, perhaps JSP has it's own issues with it.

Answer (score 7):

Eclipse does not recognize this attribute, but you can configure the HTML Validation preferences to ignore it.

Under Preferences for HTML Files --> Validation there is an option to ignore specified attribute names. If you want you can enter a pattern here such as `data-*`.

Answer (score 0):

This warning isn't shown with Eclipse Luna so upgrading your Eclipse version should make this go away.

Comment: I see this warning in Eclipse Luna and in Mars RC2, so I don't think upgrading is sufficient. You can however configure Eclipse to ignore specific attributes that you know are OK.