# Undefined attribute name (role) , eclipse

Tags: jquery, eclipse, twitter-bootstrap, undefined

I have a following file structure

WebContent->bootstrap->

js

css

img

WebContent->index.jsp

None of the following two urls are helping to resolve undefined attribute error.

[Undefined attribute name (data-toggle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988208/undefined-attribute-name-data-toggle)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
<span class="label label-primary">Primary</span>
<span class="label label-success">Success</span>
<span class="label label-info">Info</span>
<span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
<span class="label label-danger">Danger</span>
<a href="#">Inbox <span class="badge">42</span></a>


</div>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <p>...</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Eclipse version details are listed below.
Spring Tool Suite

Version: 3.6.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 201408250818
Platform: Eclipse Luna (4.4)

Copyright (c) 2007 - 2014 Pivotal Software, Inc.
All rights reserved. Visit http://spring.io/tools/sts

This product includes software developed by the
Apache Software Foundation http://www.apache.org

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is this? Is data-toggle valid in this version of HTML? What's the second of the two URLs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

is for HTML 4.01.

[`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#data-*) were added in HTML 5. [The doctype for HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#the-doctype) is basically either

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
```

It's also quite possible that your IDE isn't aware of HTML 5 and its many changes.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Eclipse support HTML5 tags and the data-* attributes allowed in HTML5. However, when using the role attribute the proper syntax according to the ARIA Roles Model and XHTML Role Attribute Module is not to prefix the role attribute with data-* leaving just role and not data-role.

So `<ul role="menubar">` is more correct than `<ul data-role="menubar">`. The validity of the syntax can be checked using the (X)HTML5 Validator. jQuery Mobile uses quite extensively the data-role attribute, though I'm not sure why.

Note: If you upgrade and you're still getting warnings on data-* attributes you may want to consider updating or removing any installed syntax-checkers such as JTidy. As of Indigo Service Release 1 the role attribute continues to trigger an undefined attribute warning in Eclipse by default.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Eclipse-Helios, here's what i did:

From the tool bar:

> Window>preferences>Web>Validation>Attributes,

Then change

> "Undefined attribute name"

from

> 'error'

or

> 'warning'

to

> 'ignore'

.

[helios.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQIgI.png)