# Can i use Bootstrap CDN in a JSP file with Eclipse?

Tags: html, eclipse, maven, jsp, bootstrap-4

I am making a WebProject in Maven for my institute, i want to use the links BootstrapCDN in my jsp file but eclipse sendme 2 warnings:

Undefinied Attribute name (crossorigin) JSP Problem &
Undefinied Attribute name (integrity) JSP Problem

This problem is in link CSS and JS from CDN bootstrap

Someone know how to fixit? or bootstrap works with this warnings?

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Registro - Tienda Online</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Registro de Usuario</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined attribute name (data-toggle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988208/undefined-attribute-name-data-toggle)

Comment: try using `maxcdn` link instead of `stackpath` and see if that works?